# SQL query to find references of keys satisfying condition C and not satisfying NOT C

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find key corresponding to records of table `A` referenced in table `B` where only condition `C` is satisfied.
Since they can be multiple references to each `A` key in `B` part of them can satisfy `C` and some others not. If a key (in `A`) has both references in `B` satisfying `C` and others not this should not be reported in results.

I tried with the following script:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT id
FROM
   A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id_A
WHERE C
```

but obviously this does not work as some elements are not excluded from the results.

--- Update *2021-11-09* ---

#### Table A:

| id | value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Aaaaaa |
| 1 | Bbbbbb |
| 2 | Cccccc |
| 3 | Dddddd |

And of course

#### Table B:

| id | id_A | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Plate1 | M |
| 1 | 1 | Plate2 | M;S |
| 2 | 1 | Plate3 | M;P; |
| 3 | 0 | Plate4 | S;P |
| 4 | 3 | Plate5 | M |

`C` condition should be

```
(Table B.value2 = 'M')
```

Should result in:

| id |
| --- |
| 3 |

since `id_A = 0` satisfy condition `C` in the first row but doesn't not in row 3 while `id_A = 3` statisfy only condition `C`.

Comment: Add `AND id NOT IN (query that finds rows that satisfy NOT C)`

Comment: Remove WHERE and add C to the JOIN condition.

Comment: @LukStorms added sample data .

Comment: Why doesn't id_A1=1 also get returned in this example? Both of its rows in B satisfy the condition.

Comment: It's a *lost-in-editing* issue... someone decided to beautify my old style tables formatting tables in a nicer way and cut down some data... I'm fixing it now.
The real problem was the char used by SO to format tables ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple Group By with a Having should do it.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.id_A = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN b.value2 = 'M' THEN b.id END);
```

This should find the lone M's

To get more than just the id's, try this

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM TableB b
JOIN TableA a ON a.id = b.id_A
WHERE b.value2 = 'M'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM TableB b2
     WHERE b2.id_A = b.id_A
       AND b2.id != b.id
       AND b2.value2 != b.value2
  );
```

Comment: looks like it works ;-)

Comment: Luk you need a medal for this. I read the question 3 times and still couldnt figure whats the point..

Comment: @BoppityBop it took me two days thinking to find the way to explain....

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some logic to achieve this. I have given you an example below, hope it helps.

Also if you already have a foreign key in table B then for your use case you don't even need to join.

First write a case statement to flag those which satisfy your condition and load to temporary table. I am flagging those that satisfy your condition as 0 and those which do not as 1.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE staging_table
Select id ,id_A , value1 , value2 , case when value2 = 'M' then 0 else 1 
end as condC from tableB
Limit 0;
```

Then just return the Id which satisfy your condition.

```
Select id_A from staging_table group by id_A having sum(condC)=0
```

Don't forget to drop your temporary table if you don't need it.